# Grid is not being updated in a for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm updating near 4500 product using for loop and `urllib` request. Here is my code.

```
def buttons(self):
   ...
    Button(self.main_gui, text='Start', command=self.prepare_xml).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
   ...

def prepare_xml(self):
    status = Label(self.main_gui, text="---//===//----", fg="red")
    status.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, padx=4)
    ...
        for product in root.findall('Product'):
           status.configure(text='Product: ' + product.find('stock_code').text)
           ...
           time.sleep(1)
```

My code is work but after the click Start button. It wait pressed and not update the **status** with the loop.

How can I update the status at every iteration of the loop?

Comment: Have you done any research to solve this? There are many, many, many questions on this site related to tkinter, loops, and calling `sleep`. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: i make a research using button and command keys. Now i made a search using tkinter, loops, and calling sleep. You are right. I see a lot of questions. I will try to use command `main_gui.update()`. Then i will write results.

Comment: @user5510975 You probably want to use the method `after`. Check around how it works ;)

Comment: main_gui.update() is worked for me.